# Horizontal dipole radiation gaps

Tags: 2m-band, dipole, polarization, radiation-pattern

Consider the radiation pattern of a horizontal dipole mounted at a height of 1.75λ. Is it possible for a receiving station's antenna to be mounted at a certain height such that the radiation of the transmitting station misses the receiving antenna completely?

[image: Horizontal Dipole Radiation Patters]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible for a receiving station's antenna to be mounted at a certain height such that the radiation of the transmitting station misses the receiving antenna completely?

In theory yes.

But in practice not entirely. Real dipoles are not mounted over infinitely large, perfectly flat, perfectly conductive planes, so the nulls will not be so deep as these idealized images suggest. Furthermore, there's likely more than one path between transmitter and receiver, taking into account reflections off mountains, trees, buildings, ionospheric changes, feedline radiation, etc. In practice there are dozens of things which make the path work (or not), and many of them are constantly changing or difficult to predict. Antenna height is just one factor.